# Angular: 7.2.1 ES6 class ReferenceError : Cannot access 'X' before initialization

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, es6-class

I'm having the following TypeScript class

```
export class Vehicule extends TrackableEntity {
  vehiculeId: number;
  constructor() {
    super();
    return super.proxify(this);
  }
}
```

my typescript target in tsconfig.json is configured as es6:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
}
```

At runtime, here in Chrome, the code is failing with:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Vehicule' before initialization
    at Module.Vehicule (https://localhost:44338/src-app-components-dispositifsDATI-dispositifsDATI-module.js:10559:100)
    at Module../src/app/domain/models/VehiculeGpsBoxInfo.ts (https://localhost:44338/src-app-components-dispositifsDATI-dispositifsDATI-module.js:11156:69)
    at __webpack_require__ (https://localhost:44338/runtime.js:84:30)
    at Module../src/app/domain/models/Vehicule.ts (https://localhost:44338/src-app-components-dispositifsDATI-dispositifsDATI-module.js:10571:78)
    at __webpack_require__ (https://localhost:44338/runtime.js:84:30)
    at Module../src/app/components/dispositifsDATI/mainDATI/listDATI/listDATI.component.ts (https://localhost:44338/src-app-components-dispositifsDATI-dispositifsDATI-module.js:6447:82)
    at __webpack_require__ (https://localhost:44338/runtime.js:84:30)
    at Module../src/app/components/dispositifsDATI/index.ts (https://localhost:44338/src-app-components-dispositifsDATI-dispositifsDATI-module.js:3053:95)
    at __webpack_require__ (https://localhost:44338/runtime.js:84:30)
    at Module../src/app/components/dispositifsDATI/dispositifsDATI.routes.ts (https://localhost:44338/src-app-components-dispositifsDATI-dispositifsDATI-module.js:2982:64)
```

I needed to change es5 to es6 to solve [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860043/javascript-es6-typeerror-class-constructor-client-cannot-be-invoked-without-ne).

---

EDIT:
The VehiculeGpsBoxInfo.ts file is importing Vehicule like this:

```
import { Vehicule } from "./Vehicule";
```

EDIT 2: I vould say that this may be webpack related, the way that modules are exported/imported in the genrated modules.

EDIT 3: After further research, this seems to have nothing to do with the code shown above. Started a new question about [webpack and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884546/do-i-need-to-configure-webpack-for-es6).

Comment: Is it valid to `return` something in a `constructor`?

Comment: @jlang Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961778/returning-es6-proxy-from-the-es6-class-constructor)

Comment: I had this issue and found out a service I was injecting had some injections missing providers.
Check your tree

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You're probably running into this Angular issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15077.

From that issue:

> Hi, is there a reason why you need emitDecoratorMetadata to be true?
>
> This TypeScript option has a fundamental design limitation with ES2015+ code and is best avoided when targeting such output. As such this is an issue with TypeScript itself and not Angular.
>
> Angular 8+ no longer requires the option. It was also previously only required for JIT mode which is typically only used in development.

The solution is to set `"emitDecoratorMetadata": false` in your tsconfig.json file.

*Side note:*
*I must say, given that previous versions of the Angular CLI automatically added `emitDecoratorMetadata: true`, and there's no reason I can see why a dev should know that `emitDecoratorMetadata` should now be `false`, it's pretty horrible that the Angular team basically said "this isn't our problem" and closed the issue without action. This could have been easily "fixed" by adding some better documentation (as pointed out by someone in the linked issue).*

Comment: You can use https://github.com/cexbrayat/angular-cli-diff to check a lot of stuff, included tsconfig

Answer (score 101):

I was getting this error due to a circular dependency, like

- A injected with B
- B injected with C
- C injected with A

Removing the circular dependecy fixed this error.

Comment: This is definitely relevant and helped me figure out my issue.
In my case I had a service S provided by ModuleA, used internally and by ModuleB (that didn't import ModuleA). This wasn't quite the issue, but rather that service S should've been provided by ModuleC instead.

Comment: I had a circular dependency as well. Once I fixed it everything was fine again. thanks

Comment: It was also my case, thank you !

Answer (score 31):

to find circular dependencies :

npx madge --circular --extensions ts ./

(build before)

Comment: What is madge? it a tool?

Comment: omg, this tool is indispensable, thank you!

Comment: I logged in just to vote your answer. This tool is a MUST BE!

Answer (score 26):

Note that this error can also be caused by defining two public `@Injectable` classes within the same `.ts` file.

I've tripped over this more than once when I'm just prototyping stuff locally (especially when refactoring one service into multiple).

Setting `emitDecoratorMetadata: false` does fix this situation as well; but in case you're in a hurry to fix something or don't want fiddle with the`tsconfig.json` file on a large project - it's useful to know that you might be able to fix it by just moving one of the classes into a new file.

Comment: Wow you saved my life, I had the issue and it was due to a public injection within the component .ts file.

Comment: Yup, guilty. Uhlala.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this due to the order of my import statements in the module. A file that also accessed the component had to be imported before the component.

Comment: This was it for me. Thanks for throwing this in the answers!

Comment: This was it for me. In my case, I did "organize imports" shortcut in VS code, and some services were imported before the AppComponent in main.ts. Making AppComponent appear first solved the problem.

Comment: This helped me though, in my case, the source of the error was in  my library and I just moved the directive that caused the error to the top of its file. I bet I could have changed the export order in the public-api.ts as well. I can't believed it worked... seems flaky.

Comment: Check whether you have changed your imports. That was an case by me. Difficult to find.

Answer (score 3):

## Circular dependency is the devil!

It causes the whole dependency loop to be unresolvable by the compiler. In most cases, the errors look like you are not importing the classes at all.

Some might think that circular dependencies should only be prevented in services and modules, However, circular dependency should be prevented in all forms, even in models, components, and classes.

When you have circular dependency it's a sign that (sooner or later) you need to refactor and restructure your code. The following hints might be useful to do so. Suppose we want to remove the circular dependency between two classes A, B.

**Solution 1: Union/Merge**

A and B are following the very same concept and they can be merged into a single class.

**Solution 2: Separation/Creation**

There should be a new class C, that both A and B rely on or sits somewhere between those two.

***According to my experience, in most cases, the circular dependency happens because the developer tends to merge n logics into k (k<n) classes.***

Comment: that's why everybody is abandoning angular

Comment: @DinaFlies Circular dependencies between modules are considered an anti-pattern because of their negative effects regardless of the platform. So it's not about angular or a specific platform.

Comment: I've missed the part I've mentioned circular dependencies. While angular has extra-complexity to deal with modules, other frameworks simply import their components where they are needed.

Answer (score 3):

I see that in 2023 there is no correct answer, but this problem is listed high enough in google.
So basically what you need to do in scenario:

- A injected with B
- B injected with C
- C injected with A

Put all tree components in one separate module.ts e.g. `abc.module.ts`.
In that file you can event simpler put all components in array like this:

`export const components = [ AComponent, BComponent, CComponent, ];`

and then in `@NgModule {}` add this array to:
`exports: [components], declarations: [components],`

`imports:[]` array has all dependant components which are used by those tree. And thats it, you will be safe from `ReferenceError : Cannot access 'X' before initialization`

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 8, having `entryComponents` declared as an empty list in a SharedModule caused this issue for me:

```
entryComponents: []
```

After removing `entryComponents`, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

For people landing here from a search: When you get this error in Angular 15 or above, it might be due to circular dependencies at `standalone` components. In that case you can fix it with [forwardRef](https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef):

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-b',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./b.scss'],
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => AComponent))
  ]
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76233363/11603006

Comment: Thanks you! This saved my day. Everyone is suggesting removing the circular dependency, while it is a bug in most cases, when you are building some sort of a nested ui, like a form builder, you are into the circular world where components have to be re-used along the same tree. This is the way for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an `index.ts` file that exported components from `A.ts` and `B.ts`.

`B.ts` tried to import from the `index.ts` instead of `A.ts`.

This caused the MJS to be emitted in the incorrect order because of the cycle:

```
B.ts -> index.ts -> B.ts
```

You can search for imports ending in `from "."`. This can be avoided by using a underscored prefix `_index.ts` (except in the root directory).

I'm posting this for others looking for other ideas that cause `Cannot access 'X' before initialization`. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it wasn't any circular dependency, it was a bug in an array that I export and use inside one of the components.

The array is multidimensional and I used one of the indexes without initializing it first, when I opened the project I got the error:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'XXXModule' before initialization

I started reverting back the files one by one until I found the exact issue, but really weird how I didn't get another error explaining the wrong use of an array.

Answer (score 0):

For those still searching for another solution to this error, I found out that I had two equal imports in a Parent Component and Child Component and that was giving me this error .

Example:

ParentComponent and ChildComponent both have this import:

```
import { ExampleComponent } from '../example-component/example-component.component'
```

The solution was to remove that one line of import in one of them and the error stop

Hope this saves someone's time

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when I was adding another folder / entrypoint to a library. I had multiple components and was importing one into the other. The default import path VSCode used was `./public-api`. Changing it to the actual component path (`../folder/file`) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My issue with this was having a Service that had the wrong providedIn configuration, and I must have been providing and importing the service wrong in the actual component or somewhere else down the tree. Anyway, I only needed one instance at the root, so changing providedIn back to 'root' fixed it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First i checked if I had any circular dependency, but didn't find any (in my case is an almost empty project). Then i discovered that adding this line:

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
```

inside polyfills.ts file, fixes the issue.

I can't explain why, hope comments will

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

that make sense, you are passing the local object (`Vehicle`) to the parent class within constructor `return super.proxify(this);`.

Keep in mind the local `Vehicle` instance has not been instantiated yet (constructor block is not finished yet), so you cannot use this object in the mean time, you need to wait the constructor to done it's job.