# Do I need to configure webpack for ES6?

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-modules

I have an angular app with a .tsconfig file targeting ES6.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "es2018.promise"
    ]
  }
}
```

The following angular component (Typescript):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { DispositifsDATIRoutingModule } from './dispositifsDATI.routes';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { DISPOSITIFS_DATI_COMPONENTS } from './index';

import { InputUtilitiesModule } from 'ng-uikit-pro-standard';
import { MaterialChipsModule, BadgeModule, IconsModule, WavesModule } from 'ng-uikit-pro-standard';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DispositifsDATIRoutingModule,
    InputUtilitiesModule,
    MaterialChipsModule,
    BadgeModule,
    IconsModule,
    WavesModule
  ],

  declarations: [DISPOSITIFS_DATI_COMPONENTS]
})

export class DispositifsDATIModule { }
```

is transpiled by webpack to:

```
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "DispositifsDATIModule", function() { return DispositifsDATIModule; });
```

Which fails at runtime with:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'DispositifsDATIModule' before initialization

I have no idea what is going on here.

Is there something to change in the webpack config around the use of ES6?

---

EDIT: This seems to be an issue in [angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30141) and/ or [TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27519) regarding ES2015

Comment: I was getting this error due to an error in the ts code. When I navigated to the url of the route it gave me a more specific error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, this error was caused because I was referencing a module that was using TypeScript decorators.
I removed the decorators in favor of the equivalent API and the problem is gone.

---

**EDIT 04/09/2019**:

Just to be clear, I was using Angular 7.5 which requires [emitDecoratorMetadata](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata) to be set to true.
I just learned that my external module requires [experimentalDecorators](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#introduction) not emitDecoratorMetadata.

So, upgrading to angular 8 and setting emitDecoratorMetadata to false, allows me to use this external library.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have circular dependencies here, your component file (let's say it is `MyComponent.ts`) imports `DISPOSITIFS_DATI_COMPONENTS` from the `./index.ts` while `index.ts` imports the component from the `./MyComponent.ts`.

So they depend on each other. In that case, `DISPOSITIFS_DATI_COMPONENTS` can be not initialized by the time you use it.

I would extract it to a third file in order to avoid circular dependencies

UPD: here is an useful article https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-to-break-a-cyclic-dependency-between-es6-modules-fd8ede198596

Comment: Thanks, but after reviewing our code, this is nota a circular reference issue. Question has been updated.

Comment: The links you added are about circular dependencies. They say "we got circular dependencies here but it should not be so". 
Even so, the only way to get your error is a circular dependency. And importing something from "./index" is like evidence.