# Cannot access 'MyComponent' before initialization in Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular10

I get the `Cannot access 'MyComponent' before initialization` error message in the browser.

The `ng build` ran without errors.

I did a little research about this topic and found suggestions to update my app's `tsconfig.base.json` file with this setting:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": false
  }
}
```

It's not helped. So added this:

```
  "annotateForClosureCompiler": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true
  }
```

Also not helped. So tried to change the `target` from `es2015` to any newer but not solved the problem.

I tried to change these settings on my library too (what contains the component), but isn't helped.

I checked these discussions:

- [Same issue in Angular 7.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870661/angular-7-2-1-es6-class-referenceerror-cannot-access-x-before-initializatio)
- [Next question from Oliver Matrot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884546/do-i-need-to-configure-webpack-for-es6)
- [Property decorators break at runtime with ES2015 and circular deps on GitHub angular/angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30141)
- [ES2015 + emitDecoratorMetadata causes Cannot access before intialization on GitHub angular/angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15077)

In my case I use `10.1.6` from Angular packages:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "^10.1.6",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1001.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.1.6",
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my circular dependency on my library and the error is gone.