# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'GA' before initialization

Tags: angular, tomcat, jboss

When I run my angular application with ng serve it works. However when I am deploying (either Jboss or Tomcat Servers) same angular application it gives following at console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'GA' before initialization
    at main-es2015.faddfe3f773581d6c95a.js:1
    at Module.zUnb (main-es2015.faddfe3f773581d6c95a.js:1)
    at l (runtime-es2015.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js:1)
    at Object.0 (main-es2015.faddfe3f773581d6c95a.js:1)
    at l (runtime-es2015.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js:1)
    at t (runtime-es2015.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js:1)
    at Array.r [as push] (runtime-es2015.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js:1)
    at main-es2015.faddfe3f773581d6c95a.js:1
```

I have used `ng build --prod ---base-href=myapp` to build my module.

What could've possibly gone wrong?

Optional: 
I have already tried  `"emitDecoratorMetadata": false` based on a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870661/angular-7-2-1-es6-class-referenceerror-cannot-access-x-before-initializatio) on another thread. But still issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, I have figured out this was due to some compilation from the typescript to the javascript issue. I have managed to fix this by a workaround just by initializing GA (please note this GA is dynamically changing with each build compilation) at javascript manually after ng build. And it fixed.

A similar issue has been discussed at [Gitlab forum](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30106).

further explaining my solution:

```
    var GA; // manually declared initializing here.
    return e.ngInjectableDef=ue({factory:function(){return new GA},token:GA,providedIn:"root"})
```