# Angular dependency with "providedIn" in lazy loading modules

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

I am using Angular "Lazy-loading feature modules" as an example:
[live demo](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/lazy-loading-ngmodules/stackblitz)

**CustomersModule** is a lazy loading module i create a test service in customer module.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  constructor() { }

  getHeroes() { return "HEROES"; }
}
```

in CustomersModule, add it to providers:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomersRoutingModule } from './customers-routing.module';
import { CustomersComponent } from './customers.component';
import {TestService} from "./test.service";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CustomersRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    TestService
  ],
  declarations: [CustomersComponent]
})
export class CustomersModule { }
```

CustomersModule also has a **CustomersComponent**, by this way i can use TestService in it.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TestService} from "./test.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers.component.css']
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {


   testService: TestService;

  constructor(test: TestService) {
    this.testService = test;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  test(){
    console.log(this.testService.getHeroes());
  }
}
```

but when i remove the TestService from providers array of CustomersModule and use providedIn in TestService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CustomersModule} from "./customers.module";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: CustomersModule
})
export class TestService {
  constructor() { }

  getHeroes() { return "HEROES"; }
}
```

i got this error:

```
core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Cannot access 'CustomersModule' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'CustomersModule' before initialization
    at Module.CustomersModule (customers.component.ts:9)
    at Module../src/app/customers/test.service.ts (test.service.ts:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/customers/customers.component.ts (customers-customers-module.js:78)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/customers/customers-routing.module.ts (customers-customers-module.js:29)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/customers/customers.module.ts (customers.component.ts:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41632)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

I know there is circular dependecny here, for eagerly loaded modules it works and will enable tree-shaking.
Does it mean in lazy loading modules only providers array can be used in NgModule?

are there guidelines/best practice for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: 7.2.1 ES6 class ReferenceError : Cannot access 'X' before initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870661/angular-7-2-1-es6-class-referenceerror-cannot-access-x-before-initializatio)

Answer (score 3):

See [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25784) issue. The providedIn property is extremely confusing in this aspect.

> Does it mean in lazy loading modules only providers array can be used in NgModule?

Yes, so, unfortunately, tree-shaking is out of the picture with lazy-loaded modules.

Comment: Yes. You're right, to use the `providedIn` feature for enabling tree shaking. One need to create a dedicated module(`dedicatedModule`) just for that service which will use `providedIn: dedicatedModule`. And then can import that `dedicatedModule` in a lazy module. Thing to note here is that the `dedicatedModule` is itself not a lazy module, it has to be eager.

As of today, the `providedIn: someModule` has been deprecated since roughly 2 weeks

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely circular dependency, that looks like this

```
CustomersComponent -> TestService -> CustomersModule -> CustomersComponent -> TestService
```

that's why you are getting this exception `CustomersModule and TestService` are injecting one another, so injecting it's in the provider array (instead of providedIn), will do the same thing, so undo your changes and leave `TestService` in providers array. Angular will optimize it the same way as it would do for `providedIn` attribute

Answer (score -1):

try like this.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Let me know if you still face any issue.