# Angular 15 Ref Error: Cannot access 'Component A' before initialization

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-standalone-components

I am facing one issue while importing standalone component within each other.

Component A.

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-a',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.scss'],
  imports: [
    BComponent
  ]
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

Component B

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-b',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./b.scss'],
  imports: [
    AComponent
  ]
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

Earlier this solution was working fine for me as accessing these components with using templates. but now getting this Error.

> Ref Error: Cannot access 'AComponent' before initialization.

Any help in above context is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pick a component and use [forwardRef](https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef)

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-b',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./b.scss'],
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => AComponent))
  ]
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

## [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqgbou?file=src%2Fcomponent-b%2Fcomponent-b.component.ts)

Credit to El Greco / Tim Deschryver, [twitter thread](https://twitter.com/tim_deschryver/status/1656353733356273665?s=20)

Comment: what if AComponent need to import in mutiple standalone component? should we need to use forwardRef in all other standalone component?